# Exporting to odt suddenly fails

Tags: org-export

Exporting to odt used to work fine in the past, until today, where I suddenly experienced the following error:

```
OpenDocument export failed: You’re not in a project
```

What could the source be?
What shall I do to remove this message?

Comment: Are there any other relevant messages in the *Messages* buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`M-x eval-expression` to evaluate below Emacs Lisp expressions:

- `(executable-find "zip")`
- `(executable-find "soffice")`

Make sure these two executable added into environment variable "PATH"

Comment: If zip is not present, the error would have been `Executable "zip" needed for creating OpenDocument files`, at least in current org (9.0.8 or so).  And I presume that since it "used to work", both of them are still present. But it doesn't hurt to double check.

Comment: @chenbin Thanks, it sort of was and was not the cause. Strangely enough I did not find the executable. My path pointed to a version 4, but I have version 5 now. Pobably an update? Anyway, fixing that, however, did not resolve my issue. I have not found an indication that I customized the position of soffice. What could I check next? PS: zip can be found.

Comment: Ah, and exeuting soffice from emacs works...

Comment: `M-x org-version` and `M-x emacs-version`? and `C-h v org-odt-convert-processes` (suppose you use org v8)? Its value is `(("LibreOffice" "soffice --headless --convert-to %f%x --outdir %d %i")
 ("unoconv" "unoconv -f %f -o %d %i"))` on my computer (I use org 8). See http://orgmode.org/manual/Extending-ODT-export.html